# Error while creating react app using npm or npx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am getting an error when I create react app following screenshot is an error:

Node.js version v12.18.1

npm version v6.14.5

I am creating a project using these commands:

1. I added create-react-app globally using this `npm install -g create-react-app`
2. I created a project using the following command `create-react-app demo`

[image]

3. I checked for `npm audit` and got the following answer

[image]

I also used this following method to create a project

```
npx create-react-app demo
```

but I also got an error in this too. but this error is too long to add to this question.
Please, give me some solution for this problem. until then I can't work forward.

Comment: I have v12.18.1 in the node. I checked in reactjs.org it says this Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6

Comment: Please try this **npx create-react-app demo**

Comment: I've tried that too I'm getting error in that too.

Answer (score 0):

In create-react-app documentation says:

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#quick-start

And just use: `npx create-react-app demo`

Comment: can I have to install yarn globally?

Comment: Yes. You can install yarn globally

Comment: Please, give me command to install yarn globally or anything that can help.

Comment: i've tried to install yarn but i can't able to install it

Comment: Can I ask you for what you should install yarn?

Comment: i've downloaded .msi file from the following web https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable but it doesn't show in command prompt

Comment: If you windows user, download that and go to download folder and run the downloaded file

Answer (score 0):

I have node v12.13.0 and npm 6.12.0. Try `npx create-react-app demo`
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhyYF.png)

Comment: I've tried many versions of node and npm including yours, but the error is coming

Comment: You can try to uninstall the `create-react-app`  module and install it again